What is this "Meta" site? How does it work and why should I use it?
There's two separate yet related Stack Exchange sites for Cognitive Sciences:

The "main" site, cogsci.stackexchange.com
This "meta" site, meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com

Why are there two? What is this site? Why does it exist? How do I use it?

All Stack Exchange sites have two parts: a main question and answer site, and what is known as a meta site, also called a "per-site meta" or a "child meta".
The main site is where all the on-topic questions and answers go. This is where you ask a question about cognitive science, psychology (e.g., cognitive, social, developmental, biological, applied, clinical, organizational, etc.), psychiatry, neuroscience and neurobiology
The meta site is the site you're on now. The purpose of the meta site is to ask questions about the main site. The meta site is the community's way of discussing issues and making decisions which pertain to our community.
Having two sites allows us to have a common interface for Q&A and also for community discussion, while also keeping the actual content separate from the "meta discussion"
Meta is how you can take an active role in shaping your community!
Just like the main site, topics on Meta are listed as questions. Some of the questions are users asking for help or support using the main site. Most of the questions are community members discussion issues about this community. There are also bug reports listed on Meta.
How do I use Meta? How can I participate?
Just like the main site, if you have a question about how the site works, need help, or want to discuss anything about the community, click Ask Question in the top right. Make sure to tag your question with support, discussion, or bug depending on the nature of your question.
Be sure to check for featured questions. These are the questions which our community needs some input on!
Also, be sure to browse all discussion questions. By providing answers to discussion questions or by upvoting existing answers, you are helping to shape this community! Your input matters!
Votes on Meta are different!
There is no reputation on Meta. Your reputation number is the same as on the main site. Upvotes on Meta mean "I agree" or "I like this", and similarly downvotes mean "I disagree" or "I don't think this is a good idea". By voting on Meta questions and answers, you're helping to shape the community by directing the moderators and the Stack Exchange team. We really do listen to the community's voice, and Meta is that voice!
